# How to use commands in table specs, and still support array package?

Tags: tables, best-practices, expansion

For a package, I want to write code that creates tables, where the exact type of table is configurable (`tabular`, `longtable`, `tabularx`, ... **[Update:** David rightly remarked that formats like `tabularx` would be harder to use in a configurable way, as they need more parameters**]**), and where the number of columns is determined by the program (so table specs like `l|l` are computed; details do not matter here). The following simple code works with LaTeX tables:

```
\def\mytablespec{l|l}
\def\mytabletype{tabular}
\begin{\mytabletype}{\mytablespec}
1 & 2 \\\hline
3 & 4 \\
\end{\mytabletype}
```

However, if the package `array` is loaded, the code fails with the error

```
Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\mytablespec): `c' used.
```

The problem is that `array` does not expand table specs. One can force this as follows:

```
\def\mytablespec{l|l}
\expandafter\tabular\expandafter{\mytablespec}
1 & 2 \\\hline
3 & 4 \\
\endtabular
```

This code works with or without the `array` package. However, this code no longer uses a command to define the table type. I did not manage to combine `\expandafter` with `\begin{\mytabletype}...\end{\mytabletype}`. The following, however, seems to work:

```
\expandafter\csname\expandafter\mytabletype\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\mytablespec}
1 & 2 \\\hline
3 & 4 \\
\csname end\mytabletype\endcsname
```

**[Update:** David pointed out that the following simpler version also works:

```
\csname\mytabletype\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\mytablespec}
1 & 2 \\\hline
3 & 4 \\
\csname end\mytabletype\endcsname
```

**]**

Besides being quite ugly, this assumes that environments like `tabular` and `longtable` always provide two corresponding commands, such as `\tabular` and `\endtabular`. This seems to be the case for many packages, but I could not find out if there is a general reason why this should be the case.

Is this the right way to solve this problem? Is there a cleaner/easier solution? In general, the behaviour of tables changes quite a bit if `array` is loaded (it also modifies table width computation in incompatible ways); is there maybe a more general approach to make packages robust against such things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have more `\expandafter` than needed

```
\csname\mytabletype\expandafter\csname\expandafter{\mytablespec}
```

would work for the  `\mytabletype`  `tabular` case, although I'm not sure how your actual code copes with the different argument structure, in particular `tabular`{`*`,`x`,`y`} taking a width argument that `tabular*` and `longtable` don't take.

The best way to not have to worry about the other changes that `array` makes is just to add `\RequirePackage{array}`. The `array` package has been part of the core LaTeX distribution since 2e came out in 1993, The only reason it's not part of the format is to avoid affecting tables written for LaTeX 2.09, but that shouldn't affect documents using a new package under construction.

Comment: Thanks; I did not know that one can expand "out of" csname. However, `\csname\mytabletype\expandafter\csname{\mytablespec}` does not work for me. It works if I insert another `\expandafter` before `{` though. You are right about the other tabular types; I am mainly trying to make `longtable` optional. In this sense, I probably do not need to worry whether other table environments provide corresponding `\end...` commands.

Comment: @mak Thanks I corrected my answer. (It was trying to expand `{` which is not expandable).

Comment: @David Carlisle Is there any method, to put commands in a row to the tablespec....

\providecommand{\hlttextacs}{}
\providecommand{\hlttextacs}{}
\newcommand{\tablecolumndira}{M}
\newcommand{\tablecolumndirb}{M}
\renewcommand{\hlttextacs}{3}
\renewcommand{\hlttextacs}{4}
\def\mytablespec{\tablecolumndira{\hlttextacs cm}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.2em}\tablecolumndirb{\hlttextbcs cm}}

Comment: it's best to ask new questions as new questions rather than comments on old ones (as you see formatting in comments is poor and most people won't see the question You should not be using `\def` just use `\newcolumntype` macros defined via that do get expanded