# Using conditionals in tabular preamble with array

Tags: tables, conditionals, etoolbox

I'm trying to use a conditional in the column setup for my `tabular`. That is, the definition of one column (actually several columns) is dependent on a boolean value (as set up from the `etoolbox` package).

I need the `array` package too, but once I add it in (or other packages that rely on it), I get an error:

```
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\ifbool): `c' used.
```

I've tried packing my column definition into a new column type as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12236), as well as some `csname` tricks described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103946/how-to-use-commands-in-table-specs-and-still-support-array-package), to no avail.

Here's a minimal (non-)working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{array}

\newbool{MyBoolean} \setbool{MyBoolean}{true}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
    l
    \ifbool{MyBoolean}{c}{}
    r
}

Left & \ifbool{MyBoolean}{Center &}{} Right \\
Left & \ifbool{MyBoolean}{Center &}{} Right
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Related/duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/easiest-way-to-delete-a-column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use [`collcell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) to collect and conditionally set the column entry:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,array,collcell}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\usermacro}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcommand{\usermacro}[1]{\ifbool{MyBoolean}{#1}{\hspace*{-2\tabcolsep}}}

\newbool{MyBoolean}

\begin{document}

% Control tabular    
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  Left & Center & Right \\
  Left & Center & Right
\end{tabular}

\setbool{MyBoolean}{true}
\begin{tabular}{ l C r }
  Left & Center & Right \\
  Left & Center & Right
\end{tabular}

\setbool{MyBoolean}{false}
\begin{tabular}{ l C r }
  Left & Center & Right \\
  Left & Center & Right
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The correction for a false boolean is to remove any column separation (of width `\tabcolsep`) using a negative space.

Comment: Thanks; I think this is getting me in the right direction. Unfortunately, my _real_ need is more complicated (in a way I didn't anticipate) than the example I put above. I need the C column to take a width parameter (like `p{2cm}`). Ideally I would also pass it the boolean to decide whether or not to make the column (rather than having `\usermacro` do that) but it's not a big deal.

Comment: @Jonah: It is possible to make `C` accept an argument like `p{2cm}`. If you're always have either the `C`-column or not, then it seems sufficient to have a macro construct the column (correcting the spacing if it actually doesn't exist).

Comment: It required some more finicking because I actually wanted to use a custom column with argument, but turned out not to be a big deal. Thanks for the help!